# How do I get the BitmapData from a local image in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

The image is already held locally on the client PC and it is an Air application. The image is not embedded, it is in the Application Storage directory.

I have seen this question: [How can i get a BitmapData object out of a File object from a local jpeg file in AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547859/how-can-i-get-a-bitmapdata-object-out-of-a-file-object-from-a-local-jpeg-file-in) but it uses URLRequest which I don't think is what I need because the file is local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using file.url will give you a url you can use with a URLRequest even though the file is local.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the image file using `FileStream` class's `readBytes()` method? This will give you a `ByteArray` representation of the image. I think you can create a new `BitmapData` Object using this info. I haven't tested this myself.